# Why my conversion specifiers doesn't work properly in C

Tags: c, string, scanf, format-specifiers, format-conversion

I'am quite new in **C** and dealing with text formatting that is a bit challenging for me.
I try to enter initials *J. S.* (whitespace between characters) and name *John Smith* and my **initials** array stores the value **J. S.John Smith** that is not what should be.

Can somebody explane me why it is happening.

Here is my code snippet ( just example )

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>

struct Person
{
    char initials[5];
    char name[35];
};

int main(void)
{
    struct Person person;
    printf("Please enter symbols: ");
    scanf("%6[^\n]%*c", person.initials);
    printf("%s\n", person.initials);
    printf("Please enter your name: ");
    scanf("%35[^\n]%*c", person.name);
    printf("%s\n", person.name);
    printf("%s\n", person.initials);
}
```

Output :

```
Please enter symbols: J. S.
J. S.
Please enter your name: John Smith
John Smith
J. S.John Smith
```

Will be very thankful for help.

Comment: What is there scanf("%6[^\n]%*c", person.initials); used the magic number 6?

Comment: You go out of bounds of the `initials` array. You tell `scanf` to read 6 characters *plus* the null-terminator (for a total of 7 characters) into an array of only 5 elements.

Comment: On another note, there are better ways to skip the trailing newline from the previous `scanf` calls: Add a single leading space in your `%[]` formats. As in `scanf(" %34[^\n]%*c", person.name)` (also note how I changed the width specifier)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `initials` array isn't large enough to store what you're entering.

The string "J. S." consists of 5 characters plus a terminating null byte for a total of 6 bytes.  `initials` is only 5 bytes wide so you overrun the buffer.

Also, the sizes you're using for the `scanf` formats is not correct.  They should be one less than the size of the array to account for the terminating null byte when a string is read.

Change `initials` to be large enough to hold the desired string:

```
char initials[6];
```

And change the formats to correctly state the largest string they can hold.

```
scanf("%5[^\n]%*c", person.initials);
scanf("%34[^\n]%*c", person.name);
```

Comment: A more general suggestion is never use `scanf()` for user (or file) input, always read to a fixed buffer (e.g `fread()`), then parse using `sscanf()` or something else. `scanf()` has too many problems with getting buffer sizes and arguments right to ever be sure it's free of vulnerabilities.